# django - post_save - Order matching query does not exist error

Tags: django, forms, view

To create an instance of `WishList` model and and instance of `Order` model when a `Profile` model is created, and to create an instance of `Profile` model when a `User` is registered, so it goes like this:

user register —> `User` —> `Profile` —> `WishList` and `Order`

the series of creation, I thought ‘post_save’ signal would be the best, and the code goes:

```py
# to create a profile whenever a user is created
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="create_user_profile")
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user_profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    if created:
        user_profile.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile, dispatch_uid="create_user_wish_list")
def create_wish_list(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user_wish_list, created = WishList.objects.get_or_create(profile=instance)
    user_wish_list.save()

# to create a shopping_bag/order whenever a profile is created
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile, dispatch_uid="create_profile_order")
def create_profile_order(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not Order.objects.get(profile=instance, is_ordered=False):
        profile_order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            profile=instance, 
            ref_number="{}'s shopping bag".format(instance.user.username),
            )
        profile_order.save()
```

They were originally in three different directories according to their own apps (`users` app: `Profile` model; `wishlist` app: `WishList` model; `shopping` app: `Order` model), and they worked fine when a registered user logged in, such as a superuser I created at the beginning of the entire profile. However, when a new user is registered, after submitting the `RegistrationForm`, this error occurs:

> Order matching query does not exist.

view.py

```py
def register_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=new_user.username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

form.py:

```py
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Пароль"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
        )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Подтверждение пароля"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=_("Введите пароль ещё раз")
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', ]

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Пароли не совпадают')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if not Order.objects.get(profile=instance, is_ordered=False)` statement is wrong. Because get() method raise  model DoesNotExist exception if object not exists so you can use `if not Order.objects.filter(profile=instance, is_ordered=False).exists()` instead of get() query.